# Reverse Proxy unexpected EOF reading request body

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I'm using the following code to read the request body in my reverse proxy:

```
func (env *Env) handleRequestAndRedirect(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    readCloserForParams, readCloserForProxy, err := getRequestBodyCopies(responseWriter, request.Body)

    if err == nil {
        //process request and other stuff...
        serveReverseProxy(urlValue, responseWriter, request)
    } else {
        responseWriter.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

func getRequestBodyCopies(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, requestBody io.ReadCloser) (io.ReadCloser, io.ReadCloser, error) {
    sizeLimit := utils.Viper.GetInt64(RequestSizeLimit) //9200000 bytes. My requests are 9836 bytes, based on the Content-Length header
    limitedReaderBody := http.MaxBytesReader(responseWriter, requestBody, sizeLimit)

    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(limitedReaderBody)
    if err != nil {
        utils.Logger.Errorf("Error reading request body: [%v]. Limit size per request's body: [%d] bytes", err, sizeLimit)
    }

    rdr1 := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
    rdr2 := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
    return rdr1, rdr2, err
}
```

The problem is that some percentage of the requests (less than 1%) returns an unexpected EOF in the line `buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(limitedReaderBody)` and I don't know why. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: This is weird, because `ReadAll` should never return EOF. I looked at the code and it calls `ReadFrom()` from a bytes buffer which should never return EOF.

Comment: I'm using `go version go1.12.6 linux/amd64`. When I check my logs I see several messages like this: `[ERRO] Error reading request body: [unexpected EOF]. Limit size per request's body: [9200000] bytes`

Comment: @Edenshaw I am facing the same issue. Did you find anything?

Comment: @ashu82492, unfortunately no. It seems to be a bug in that specific version of golang. Have you tried updating the version of go? (I could not do that because it was a production deployment)